# Changing the style display from none to block in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is html code snippet

```
<li style="opacity: 1;">
    <a id="LinkDisplay" class="optionsDropDown" style="color:#FF0000;display:none" href="javascript:showThisLink('LinkId');">
</li>
```

Here is jquery function which is being called at on load

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Test");
            document.getElementById("LinkDisplay").style.diplay="block"; // line 1
            // after this line execution i should see the link as i have
            // changed the link display from none to block but it is still invisible
        });
    });
}
```

**After  line  1 execution ,  I am not sure why my link is not becoming visible?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you could just write

```
$("#elemId").show()
```

Answer (score 21):

you have not changed the display property in your code

```
 document.getElementById("LinkDisplay").style.display="block"
```

insert this code into your function after line1

Comment: It is already block. It was typo mistake. Updated the original post

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the spelling of **display** in the line:

```
document.getElementById("LinkDisplay").style.display="block";
```

Comment: This is a typo but original prroblem is something else.

Answer (score 2):

The parent `li` is set to `opacity: 0`, which makes it transparent.

You'll need to update its' opacity to 1 to make it visible.

Replace this:

```
document.getElementById("LinkDisplay").style.color = "#FF0000";
```

with this:

```
$('#LinkDisplay').show().parent('li').css({opacity: 1});
```

The second line is jQuery (since you're using jQuery already and it's easier to find the parent node) - it's finding the LinkDisplay link and changing the `display: none` to `display: block`, then alters the parent `li`'s opacity to make it visible.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ3cr/)

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like you're already using jquery so you can simplify a bit by using the $ selector syntax:

```
$('#LinkDisplay').css('display', 'block')
```

You could also use the [jQuery show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method to shorten the first part like so:

```
$('#LinkDisplay').show()
```

The jQuery selector can find elements by ID or classes using the `#` for id's and `.` for classes.  The [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method allows you to both get and set properties using a variety of methods.   And the [jQuery parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method quickly allows you to traverse upwards from an element in the DOM to find other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#LinkDisplay').css('display','block');
$('#LinkDisplay').parent().css('opacity','1');
```