# show html element onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the visibility of an element based onclick event of refreshA element

```
<a id="refreshA">Click here</a>

 <a style="display: none;" id="refreshTab"> Info</a>
```

here is the js code

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("refreshA").onclick(function () {
                document.getElementById("refreshTab").style.display = 'block';
                })
</script>
```

Comment: It should be `.onclick = function(){...`, but you better use this: `document.getElementById("refreshA").addEventListener('click', function(){ document.getElementById("refreshTab").style.display = 'block'; });`

Comment: I tried this didn't work :(

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the visibility, or is showing it a one-time thing?

Comment: I'm trying to show the element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the style display from none to block in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174133/changing-the-style-display-from-none-to-block-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript show element on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357291/javascript-show-element-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showhide(){
    document.getElementById("refreshTab").style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('refreshA').onclick=showhide;
```

See the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg528rer/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("refreshTab").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<a id="refreshA" onclick="myFunction()">Click here</a>
<a style="display: none;" id="refreshTab"> Info</a>
```

Comment: really?? Maybe you should use browser with javascript support, or enable it in your browser settings. It works.

Comment: it's enabled , this is odd! thank you for your help .